# What is difference between tf.gfile.Gfile and tf.gfile.FastGFile?

Tags: tensorflow

Does it mean tf.gfile.FastGFile is faster than tf.gfile.Gfile?
If so, why is tf.gfile.FastGFile faster?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between [`tf.gfile.Gfile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/GFile) and [`tf.gfile.FastGfile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/FastGFile). Both the classes inherit from the same single class `FileIO`. [`GFile declaration`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py#L39) and [`FastGfile declaration`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py#L46). Neither of the classes overwrites any methods of its parent class [`File_IO`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py)

Comment: is this an observation or a fact?

Answer (score 0):

According to TensorFlow developers' statements in this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12663), there is no difference between the implementation of `Gfile` and `FastGFile`. `FastGFile` will be deprecated in the future (see the [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/21490)).